# POST service in ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core, post, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to write very simple multi-platform app (iOS & Android) in visual studio. This app uses web service, uploaded on my web hosting.

This is code that call WebAPI (get & post):

```
    async void post_async(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("POST");

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var BaseAddress = "https://mywebsite";

            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(BaseAddress, null);
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine($"RESPONSE:    " + message);
            

        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: " + er.ToString());

        }

    }

    async void get_async(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var BaseAddress = "https://mywebsite";
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(BaseAddress);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"RESPONSE: " + content);
            }

            

        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: " + er.ToString());

        }

    }
```

This is very simple code for Web Api:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<string> Get()
        {
            return "get method ok";
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<string> Post()
        {
            return "post method ok";
        }
```

Very strange issue because for every void I always obtain "get method ok". So "get" is ok, but I don't understand why I cannot call post method.
I tried to use Postman: same issue.

I'm using this very simple code:

```
[ActionName("getmet")]
    public ActionResult<string> getmet()
    {
        return "get method ok";
    }

    [ActionName("postmet")]
    public ActionResult<string> postmet()
    {
        return "post method ok";
    }
```

Now of course I can call https://mywebsite/getmet or postmet and it works using postman.

If I use [HttpPost] for postmet method, on Postman I get "404 not found". Why?

Comment: Can you share the complete code of your controller class?

Answer (score 0):

```
var BaseAddress = "https://mywebsite"; //
```

URL hits get method by difualt, thats means works as **https://mywebsite/Get** where as your actual post method URL is **https://mywebsite/Post**

instead of calling a different method use code like below.

```
[HttpPost]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<string> Get()
{
    return "method ok";
}
```

OR you can use API ROUTE

OR

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get|HttpVerbs.Post)]
```

Comment: I tried to use different ROUTES using this code:

`code
[Route("/getmethod")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<string> Get()
        {
            return "get method ok";
        }


        [Route("/postmethod")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<string> Post()
        {
            return "post method ok";
        }
code`

but no result (of course I call https//mywebsite/getmethod or postmethod

Comment: At least it should give you an error like 404,500. please share with us.

Comment: using postman:

mywebsite/getmethod -> status 200 ok,
mywebsite/postmethod -> status 404 not found

Comment: "404 not found" means the server doesn't have anything that is matching the url you are requesting. Please check your route file and startup file.

Comment: What do you mean for "route file"? sorry but I'm very new to this kind of things. I just create new project in VS (ASP .Net core Web Api) and write code above